# Append Label and Div inside a Div using Javascript AppendChild

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a dynamic form where user can add more fields for additional inputs.

When user click this button:

```
<input style="font-size=12px; width:170px;" name="add" type="button" id="add" class='btn-style'/>
```

Additional set of forms will be shown in this area:

```
<div id="collegediv"></div>
```

Using this script:

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {

    var collegediv = document.getElementById('collegediv'),
    inputatt = "form-control input-sm",
    firstdivatt = "form-group",
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("class","col-sm-5");
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.setAttribute("class","form-group");
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute("class","col-sm-3 control-label input-sm");

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    collegediv.setAttribute("class",firstdivatt);
    input.type = "text";
    input.setAttribute("name", "college[]");
    input.setAttribute("placeholder","Name of College/University");
    input.setAttribute("class", inputatt);

    div.appendChild(input);
    div2.appendChild(label);
    div2.appendChild(div);
    collegediv.appendChild(div2);

};
```

The flow of the script is to

- Append a `textbox` inside the `div variable`
- Append a `label` inside the `div2 variable`
- Append a `div` inside the `div2 variable` also
- Then append the `div2` inside the `collegediv` div

I'm also using bootstrap in the process, so the styling of `<div>` is like that.

My problem is that it doesn't format the way I think it should output.

Output/HTML SHOULD look like this:

```
<div id="collegediv">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="college" class="col-sm-3 control-label input-sm"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" name="college[]" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Name of College/University" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to be the output. My guess is that the appending of `label` and `div` inside the `div2` is the problem. It's like they have conflict or overwriting the `label` with `div` once you append it also inside `div2`. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: The output of your script is the same as you desired accept for label doesn't a for attribute?

Comment: @Syahrul The last html sample is my desired output. But this doesn't seem to be the output.

Comment: Your sample = the html output using the script except for a few attributes which you can add.

Answer (score 3):

This outputs EXACTLY what you said you wanted in your **Output/HTML SHOULD look like this:** section

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {

    var collegediv = document.getElementById('collegediv');

    //  Make first div    
    var div_form_group = document.createElement('div');
        div_form_group.setAttribute("class","form-group");

    //  Make label
    var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('for','college')
        label.setAttribute('class','col-sm-3 control-label input-sm');

    //  Make inner div
    var div_inner = document.createElement('div');
        div_inner.setAttribute('class','col-sm-5');

    //  Make input
    var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.setAttribute('name', 'college[]');
        input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control input-sm');
        input.setAttribute('placeholder','Name of College/University');
        input.setAttribute('required','required');

    //  Attach elements
    div_inner.appendChild( input );
    div_form_group.appendChild( label );
    div_form_group.appendChild( div_inner );
    collegediv.appendChild( div_form_group );

};
```

Comment: It looks like the same with my post, just clearer and with different variable names.

Comment: That's exactly what it is.  Although, your code did some things that didn't agree with your stated desired Output. Those were: extra class `form-group` added to `#collegediv`, missing `for="college"` on your `<label>`, missing `required` on your `<input>`, swapped positions of `placeholder` and `class` on your `<input>`.  So now it is the exact HTML output you desired in your question.